# Type-Pathway in Defining Bind for the List Monad

Tags: haskell

In the text *Learn You A Haskell*, the list monad is defined like so:

```
instance Monad [] where
    return x = [x]
    xs >>= f = concat (map f xs)
    fail _   = []
```

Since the bind operator is supposed to convert list-values into bare-values and `concat` trims a layer of list-ness, this definition made sense at first glance. How, though, can this definition compile when the output-type of map, `[a]`, does not match the input-type of concat, `[[a]]`?

Comment: They match, if the `a` in the output of `map` happens to be a list.

Comment: so the lesson is: use different type variables for different things: if you'd say "the output-type of map is `[a]`, and the input-type of concat is `[[b]]`, you'd see the answer right away as `a ~ [b]`. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` has type `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`.

`f` has type `a -> m b`.

In the List monad the type of `f` is: `a -> [b]`,

so `map f :: [a] -> [[b]]`